# how do i open a resource file for reading in Android

Tags: android, deserialization

If I have a file in my resources (i.e. in res/raw for example), how do I open it for reading into an input stream? The file might be anything: a text file, a class seriaisation, etc.

On the PC I would use:

```
    MyClass x = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;

    fis = new FileInputStream("/home/me/Desktop/A.dat");
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    x = (MyClass)ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open files from resources in the following way:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.A));
```